# How to play mp4 via exoplayer?

Tags: android, webview, exoplayer

I have webview app I want to play mp4 files via exoplayer or any include in app media player instead playing in website, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what 'intent receivers' exoplayer handles, so, I can't say if it will work with that.  But, in general, if you use an ACTION_VIEW intent, the ACTION_VIEW will display a list of apps that can 'receive' the type of content you are sending allowing the user to choose the one they prefer.  So, the code would be something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.myvideo.mp4"), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

Have you tried using the native VideoView object?  Here is an example:

```
private VideoView videoView;

videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.myweb.com/myvideo.mp4");
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override       
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
   mp.setLooping(true);
   videoView.start();
  }
});
```

Comment: Users can easily use my videos url if they can play it through external player, I'm looking for built in player.

Comment: So, you want to play in a viewer embedded in your app, not spawn an external Activity in another app?

Comment: I'm now embedding my videos from other websites like YouTube and vidbom, so now i want to have storage vps and embed it to my website.